# FormResponse object missing when using DriveApp and Smartsheets Sync

Tags: google-apps-script

My ultimate goal is to access the contents of a file uploaded via a Google Form from within a function triggered by formSubmit.  I added some info in a comment to this question, but I think I need to update the question itself.  When I deactivate the Smartsheets Sync add-on in the web form, this all works as expected.  My theory is that the Smartsheets Sync add-on is not preserving the `Event` object in certain scenarios.

I began with:

```
function onFormSubmit (e) {
    Logger.log (e);
}
```

I set up my trigger and tested a form submission, and in the log, I saw:

```
[<datetime>] {authMode=FULL, source=Form, response=FormResponse triggerUid=<id>}
```

as expected.  I also explored the `FormResponse` object and verified that a valid Google Drive ID is in the response.

Next, I added a call to `DriveApp.getFileById`:

```
function onFormSubmit (e) {
    Logger.log (e);

    var responses = e.response.getItemResponses ();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById (responses [1].getResponse ());

    Logger.log (file);
}
```

Resubmitting a form brings up a permission error with `DriveApp`.  Not surprising, so I ran `onFormSubmit` directly from the script editor.  It failed because it was invoked without an `Event` object, but it did invoke the dialog that allowed me to grant `DriveApp` permissions.

Now, when I submit a form, the `Event` object doesn't contain a `FormResponse` object.  From the log:

```
[<datetime>] {authMode=FULL, source=Form, triggerUid=<id>}
```

So, does granting `DriveApp` permission somehow revoke permission to inspect the user's response?  Alternatively, is there another way for me to use Google App Script to access a file uploaded via a Google Form?

Comment: Some more info... I didn't mention that in my original setup, I was using the Smartsheet Sync add-on throughout.  As it turns out, when I eliminate Smartsheet Sync, the `FormResponse` object isn't missing.  The sync add-on uses a `formSubmit` trigger, too.  It's called `responseToSmartsheet`.  I haven't been able to find its source, though.

Comment: If you want the file ID of the Form, then you need to use the `source` property to get the Form, and then get the ID of the Form.  `var file = DriveApp.getFileById (e.source.getId());` [Link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getId())

Comment: I don't want the file ID of the form.  I want the file ID of the of the file uploaded via the form.  I also tried getting the `FormResponse` from the `source` field in the `Event` object, but it was still unavailable.

Comment: You are using `responses [1]` which means that you are getting the second item (question) on the Form.  Is your file upload question the second question on the Form?

Comment: Yes.  Before I granted permissions for `DriveApp`, I verified that I was getting a valid google drive file id from the form.

Comment: Delete the On Form submit trigger and re-install it.  Sometimes triggers become disconnected for some unknown reason.  I'm not sure what else could be the problem.

Comment: I had tried that, too.  I don't think it's being disconnected because it's still triggering, just without a complete `Event` object.

Comment: Try using a new Form file.  Are their editors of the Form file?  Did you move it to a team Drive?  Did you change the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The file ID is put into the file upload answer (response).  The following code gets the answer to the file upload question, which is the file ID.  Note that arrays are zero indexed, so the first question is at index zero.  This code assumes that the file upload question is the very first question.

If this answers your question, you can mark it as correct by clicking the green arrow.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var file,fileID,form,responseID,submittedResponse,uploadResponse;

  responseID = e.response.getId();//The the ID of the current reponse
  Logger.log('responseID: ' + responseID)

  form = FormApp.getActiveForm();//Get the Form that this script is bound to

  submittedResponse = form.getResponse(responseID);//Get the response that
  //was just submitted

  uploadResponse = submittedResponse.getItemResponses()[0];//This assumes 
    //that the very first question is the file upload

  fileID = uploadResponse.getResponse();//Get the file ID of the file just uploaded
  Logger.log('fileID: ' + fileID)

  file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);//Get the file

  Logger.log('file.getName(): ' + file.getName());//verify that this is
    //the correct file - and that the code is working
}
```

Comment: As indicated in the original post, the `Event e` does not contain a `response` field, so line 3 of your function will throw an exception.

Comment: Your problem is some kind of bug that is internal to Apps Script.  If you can list steps that reproduce the problem, then you should post an issue on the Issue Tracker.  [Link to Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)